# QGIS3 Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate

Tags: qgis-3, error, ubuntu

I just launched QGIS3 (2.99) after an `sudo apt-get upgrade` in Ubuntu 16.04. But I get an error on startup that says:

```
* Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
```

Screenshot below:

[image]

Is it OK to ignore it or is there something on my Lubuntu that needs to be fixed?

Comment: I get the same error (Linux Mint); I note that if I go to https://version.qgis.org/version.txt the certificate is signed.

Comment: It appears it may be a Qt problem ~ https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the QGIS 3 issues response [17546 (comments)](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17546)

> don't worry about the certificate error on the development version of qgis, press "ignore".

Comment: This is currently happening to me on the release version...albeit only when downloading through OSGeo4W.

Answer (score -1):

See the following link... this might resolve the issue.

https://opengislab.com/blog/tag/SSL+error+QGIS

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.