# "SSL Errors occurred accessing URL" QGIS 2.18.17 - Windows 10

Tags: qgis, error, ssl

Currently having this error when I start QGIS. A colleague of mine had the same error this morning on the same QGIS version, windows 10.

EDIT: I also had the same error crash my QGIS, while I was working.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but possibly related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263019/qgis3-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: I'll keep track of that post as well, cheers @nmtoken

Comment: I would check first if the error message is correct: Is the certificate of that server made for another server name? Is the certificate old? If yes, then the server admin must acquire a new and valid sertificate.